# Show rows in which there are duplicates of a concat of 2 fields for Access SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [FRUIT], [FRUIT] & "-" & [COLOR] as FruitColor
FROM FRUITS as c;
```

That returns:

```
| Fruit      | Color           | 
|:-----------|----------------:|
|   Banana   |  Banana-Yellow  |       
|   Orange   |  Orange-Orange  |     
|   Orange   |  Orange-Red     |        
|   Banana   |  Banana-Green   |       
|   Apple    |  Apple-Red      |        
|   Pear     |  Pear-Green     |
```

The original table has many combinations of Fruit and Color, however obviously, one fruit can only have one color i.e. Banana-Green is an incorrect entry. I would like to identify all those rows that have more than one Fruit-Color combination i.e. in this table that is Banana and Orange. I would like to have Access show me all these rows.

I have another code that may help:

```
SELECT [Fruit], count([Color]) as count_unique
FROM (select distinct [Fruit], [Color] from Fruits)  AS [%$##@_Alias]
WHERE [Color] NOT IN ('Blue', 'Beige') AND [Fruit] <> 'Cucumber'
GROUP BY [Fruit];
```

(I don't care about colors Blue and Beige or Cucumbers.
Which returns:

```
| Fruit      | count_unique    | 
|:-----------|----------------:|
|   Banana   |  2              |       
|   Orange   |  2              |     
|   Apple    |  1              |        
|   Pear     |  1              |
```

Maybe I can use some kind of `HAVING Count >1` , however I am unsure of how to structure this.

Solved / Solution:

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM FRUITS x 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT [Fruit], [COLOR] 
FROM FRUITS GROUP BY [Fruit], [COLOR]) AS y 
ON x.[Fruit] = y.[Fruit]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think following query will give you, the fruits which have more than one colour, that's what you wanted. Right ?.

```
SELECT [Fruit], count([COLOR]) as count_unique
FROM FRUITS
GROUP BY [Fruit]
HAVING count(COLOR]) > 1;
```

Comment: Hi Tharsan,

The count is not exactly what I am looking for. If you look at the second table in my post, I want all the rows with field 'Fruit' IF the count_unique is >1 (a.k.a all fruits that have more than 1 color). I want the actual rows (there are more than just those two fields).

Comment: You want all the other fields of Fruit table ? At the same time the fruit should have at least one color? Correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: Yes! I want all the fields but the criteria is not at least one color as all fruits have something in the color field. The criteria is that for each unique fruit i.e. banana, there is at least 2 colors across 2 rows i.e. one row with banana-green and one row with banana-yellow. I want to return those 2 rows.

Comment: May I know the other fields from the Fruit table

Comment: Well, there are quite a few (>30).I guess you can call them with `*`?

Comment: You need to do a self join to get all of the Fruits details. SELECT x.* 
FROM FRUITS x INNER JOIN 
( SELECT [Fruit],  [COLOR]
FROM FRUITS
GROUP BY [Fruit], [COLOR] ) AS y
ON x.[Fruit] = y.[Fruit]

Comment: In Group by we have to have both FRUIT and COLOR as you want both banana-green and banana-yellow

Comment: Hi J.H, did you get the result, or do you have any issues ?

Comment: Ok. Good to hear that news from you. If it's resolves your problem, could you please accept that as a valid answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Fruit, a.Fruit & "-" & a.Color AS FruitColor
FROM FRUITS AS a
WHERE 1 < ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FRUITS AS b WHERE a.Fruit = b.Fruit );
```

Kind regards, Rene